# Finding the expected value of a particular discrete random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

The probability mass function $ P $ of a discrete random variable $ X $ is given by
$$
P(x) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^{2}}{a} & \text{if $ x \in \{ -2,-1,0,1,2 \} $}; \\
0                & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

> **(a)** Find $ a $ and $ \mathbf{E}[X] $.

I have no clue how to find $ a $. I believe that $ \mathbf{E}[X] $ is just the mean of $ \{ -2,-1,0,1,2 \} $, so would it be
$$
\frac{(-2) + (-1) + 0 + 1 + 2}{5} = 0?
$$

> **(b)** What is the probability distribution of the random variable $ Z = (X - \mathbf{E}[X]) $?

I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Javant, please learn how to typeset mathematical expressions using TeX.

Comment: @Transcendental will do, thank you for edit

Answer (score 1):

Find $a$ through the fact that $1 = \sum\limits_{x=-2}^2 P(x)$ by Law of Total Probability.

$$1 = \frac 1 a\sum\limits_{x=-2}^2 {x^2}$$

Then use, $\mathsf E(X) = \sum\limits_{x=-2}^2 x~P(x)$, which is the *weighted* average.

$$\mathsf E(X) = \frac 1 a\sum\limits_{x=-2}^2 x^3$$

Finally $\Pr(Z=z) $ is found by a simple Linear Transform.

$$\begin{align}\Pr(Z=z)~=~& \Pr(X-\mathsf E(X) = z) \\ =~& P(z+\mathsf E(X)) \\ \ddots& \end{align}$$

PS: You will also need to identify the support for $Z$.

Comment: Canceling an anonymous downvote by +1